# Does a countably infinite sample of an analytic real-valued function uniquely specify its Taylor Series?

Tags: real-analysis, algorithms

**Motivation:**
Oftentimes, the runtime for an algorithm is simplified to a function on the natural numbers {0,1,2,$\dots$}. In some cases, like if we know that the algorithm runs in O($n^2$), there is an obvious extension of this function to the reals. This might be helpful if we want to use calculus.

**Question:**
I'm wondering whether an arbitrary function $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ can be extended to a unique analytic function $f^*:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. More generally, if $f$ is defined not on the Naturals, but on some arbitrary countably infinite subset of the reals, when is it possible to extend $f$ to an analytic function on $\mathbb{R}$?

**P.S.:**
This question is a little harder than the one promised in the title.

Comment: both $f(x) = 0\cdot\sin(\pi x)$ and $g(x) = 7\cdot\sin(\pi x)$ have the same restriction to the natural numbers, but are non-equal real analytic functions from R to R. You need a limit point within the domain of analyticity

Comment: Uniqueness is most certainly not the case: $f(n)=0$ can be extended to $f(x)=a \sin(k\pi x)$ for any $a\in\mathbb R$ and $k \in \mathbb Z$. The case is a little different if your subset has accumulation points, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem . This doesn't say anything about existence, though.